# Unable to run libvirt with xen on Centos 6. Fails with ioctl 3166208

Tags: redhat, xen, centos6

As per subject.

- Xen 4.2.1
- libvirt 0.10.2-18.el6
- `Linux gatto.example.com 3.8.3-1.el6xen.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Mar 16 15:16:57 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I followed the instructions given on the [Xen wiki](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/RHEL6_Xen4_Tutorial%20Xen%20Wiki) and  rebuilt the libvirt RPMS.

However, when I run virsh I get:

```
[root@gatto SPECS]# virsh capabilities
error: Failed to reconnect to the hypervisor
error: no valid connection
error: Unable to issue hypervisor ioctl 3166208: Function not implemented
```

Also in libvirtd.log:

```
2013-03-18 09:45:29.738+0000: 8973: error : xenHypervisorDoV1Op:967 : Unable to issue hypervisor ioctl 3166208: Function not implemented
2013-03-18 09:45:29.738+0000: 8973: error : xenHypervisorInit:2174 : Unable to issue hypervisor ioctl 3166208: Function not implemented
```

Google references (which appear to boil down to reference to one patch) are quite cryptic and developer oriented.

Any ideas?

Advanced thanks & Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is a known issue and the dev.centos.org Xen-C6 repo still hasn't been updated with the bug fixes.

If you require the latest libvirt RPMs, you can fetch them from the crc.id.au repo. See the following link for more information:

https://www.crc.id.au/2013/03/17/libvirt-1-0-3-for-rhel6-centos-6-available-for-testing/

If you want, you can also compile libvirt manually to rectify the issue, this is documented over at the official libvirt website:

http://libvirt.org/compiling.html

Comment: Cool advice. I was trying to proceed from the patch available from the ML, which does not apply cleanly, but I'll try this first.